# Why does canvas clearRect() fail, but fillRect() works in this django 3 bootstrap 4 example?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to use a `canvas` as a semi-transparent overlay with cutouts over an `img` tag. I can get the overlay to work, but for some reason `clearRect(x,y,width,height)` does not put the cutouts in the overlay so the image shows through the overlay. However, I can fill a rectangle with "clear" to make a cutout using `fillRect`, so I think my code is working. I don't understand why `clearRect` does not work.

The web page uses django and bootstrap 4. I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmi2018/q0abg4r2/79/) with all the ajax and template tags removed to illustrate the problem. When your mouse hovers over the button `'hover here'`, the overlay appears but only one cutout is displayed - the one using `fillRect`, but not the one using `clearRect`. This happens in both Firefox and Chrome browsers.

What am I doing wrong with the `clearRect` call?

Thanks!

Mark

UPDATE: I tried to use `fillText` to write on my canvas, and that is not working as well. What am I doing wrong with my canvas that prevents `clearRect` and `fillText` from working? I updated the jsfiddle to reflect the `fillText` problem.

Comment: Please include your code inside the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

So, I discovered how to make the code in the jsfiddle work, but I still don't understand why.

If I add these lines to the initialization of the canvas, everything works.

```
canvas.height = image.height;
canvas.width = image.width;
```

I had thought the lines

```
canvas.style.left = position.left + "px";
canvas.style.top = position.top + "px";
canvas.style.width = image.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = image.height + "px";
```

took care of initializing the canvas size, since I don't know the size of the image until the page is loaded.

If anyone can explain why this fix makes the clearRect and fillText work, please explain!

New [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmi2018/q0abg4r2/86/) that works. See the comments at the end of the script.